# add javascript variable to url

Tags: javascript, html

In short, I want to pass the site url of the user which uses the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var url = document.location.href;
</script>
<iframe src="http://localhost/page.php?site=242333&u=" + url + " scrolling="no" frameborder="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" onload="this.width = this.contentDocument.body.scrollWidth; this.height = this.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight" />
```

The problem in the following part:

```
src="http://localhost/page.php?site=242333&u=  [" + url + "]
```

How can I concatenate the JavaScript variable with the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a JavaScript variable in your HTML markup like you're trying to do. It just doesn't work. What you can do is set the frame's source in a script that comes right after the iframe in your HTML. So, something like:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" onload="this.width = this.contentDocument.body.scrollWidth; this.height = this.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight" id="pageFrame"/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var url = document.location.href;
        document.getElementById("pageFrame").src = 
         "http://localhost/page.php?site=242333&u=" + encodeURIComponent(url);
    }
</script>
```

Note that I added an ID to your iframe so that it could be accessed through `document.getElementById()` Also, I used the JavaScript `encodeURIComponent` so that the string in your url variable would be safely encoded for your source URL. This will require a corresponding decode on the server side, and since it looks like you're using PHP, that would be done using the `urldecode()` function.

Comment: What doesn't work? Does the iframe not load? Or do you receive unexpected results?

Comment: The content of `iframe` not loaded.

Comment: It looks like the code needs to be in an event handler attached to window load. See updated answer. Please be warned that your sizing code doesn't appear to work as expected though.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle I was testing with: http://jsfiddle.net/tke98srm/. You'll probably get a 404 error because the requested page doesn't exist. The code for sizing gets called, but the scrollWidth and scrollHeight values don't seem to be the right sizes. Interestingly, the sizing result is the same if you comment out the lines where it's set.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use javascript variable in html code. Just fill the src attr of  tag with javascript like for example:

```
    <iframe id="frame" src=""> ... //rest of html

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var url = document.location.href;

    document.getElementById("frame").src = "http://localhost/page.php?site=242333&u=" + url + ... //rest of src
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/page.php?site=242333&u=" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var url = document.location.href, getIframe = $("#iframe").attr("src");
$("#iframe").attr("src", getIframe + encodeURIComponent(url));
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Moreover, the author of the question might not want to use jQuery

Comment: **JavaScript DOM**

`<script type='text/javascript'>
var url = document.location.href;
document.write("<iframe src='http://localhost/page.php?site=242333&u=" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "' id="iframe"></iframe>");
    </script>`